# Vector of vectors in R?

Tags: r, vector

I have a large set of data and I'm trying to group different rows together. I will know how to group the rows by using an ID. In the dataset, these IDs are sequential.

For example,

[image]
So what I want to do is iterate through this set of data and then place the data contained in these rows into a vector of vectors for processing later. The data contained in these rows of identical ID are going to be compared with one another to categorize the groupings.

I would like my data structure to look like something like this.

```
1 -> 1 -> 1
|
V
2 -> 2
```

So row 1 would contain only data from 1 type of ID, then the next row in the vector would be a vector of another type of ID. How would I go about doing this in R? In C++ it would just be a vector of vectors but I haven't been able to figure out how to do the same in R.

Is this even the right way to be approaching this problem? Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: In R it might be a list of vectors. After an R list is a "vector".

Answer (score -1):

You would want to *work* with **Data Frames** rather than simple matrices. Have a look as the Documentation [R-tutor Data.Frames](http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/data-frame).

It is doable. Best!